# Updating a formula in a range of cells with apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to coding. Thanks for your help.

I have a budget/spend tracking spreadsheet that I maintain on a daily basis. Each month I create a new tab and track my expenses. I also have a 'totals' tab that aggregates all of my expenses across multiple categories from all of the month tabs.

My objective is to have a menu button that I can select on the 1st of the month that does the following.

1. Creates a new tab and names it with the three-letter abbreviation of the month, i.e., "Sep" [my code below does portion of this, but I need help]
2. Clears content in certain ranges on the new tab [my code below does this]
3. Copies my vlookup formula on the 'totals' tab to a new column for the new month and updates the formula from the last month to the new month (see example below). My 'totals' tab has a column for each month. The rows are my spend categories. Each cell is pulling in the spend from the month tab based on the month column that it's in. [I need help with this]

   *=iferror(VLOOKUP($A3,**Apr**!$H$14:$I$23,2,FALSE),0)*

   to

   *=iferror(VLOOKUP($A3,**May**!$H$14:$I$23,2,FALSE),0)*

My current code (which completes 1 partially and 2 completely) is below. **Looking for assistance with renaming my month tab to the three letter month (e.g.,Dec) and updating the 'totals' tab (per item 3 above).**

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var menu = ui.createMenu('New Monthly Tab');
  var item = menu.addItem('Create New Tab', 'newMonthTab');
  item.addToUi();
}

function newMonthTab () {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var tz = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), tz, 'MM');

  //duplicates and renames the tab
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().duplicateActiveSheet();
    ss.renameActiveSheet(date);

  //clears content
    ss.getRange('A15:D23').activate();
    ss.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
    ss.getRange('I8:J11').activate();
    ss.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
    ss.getRange('M2:O35').activate();
    ss.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
    ss.getRange('W1').activate();
    ss.getRange('X1:X15').copyTo(ss.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
    ss.getRange('X1:X15').activate();
    ss.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
}
```

UPDATE 2020-05-18: Below is the code from a macro I created when I do the manual update to the "totals" tab. I want this to happen when I click the "New Monthly Tab" menu but I'm unsure how to get the script to update the vlookup formula with the name of the new month tab. I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do this.

```
   function updatetotalstab() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('G3').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('F3').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=iferror(VLOOKUP($A3,Jun!$H$14:$I$23,2,FALSE),0)');
  spreadsheet.getRange('G4:G12').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('G3').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('G23').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('F23').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=iferror((index(Jun!$R$2:$R$11,match($A23,Jun!$Q$2:$Q$11,0))),0)');
  spreadsheet.getRange('G24:G36').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('G23').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('G43').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('F43').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=iferror((index(Jun!$X$2:$X$13,match($A43,Jun!$V$2:$V$13,0))),0)');
  spreadsheet.getRange('G44:G50').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('G43').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('G52:G56').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('G43').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your first question:

### The dates can be formatted according too [Simple Date Format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

For a 3-letter month, you can use:
`var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), tz, 'MMM');`

To your second question:

To extend function `newMonthTab()`'s functionalities and set a formula with a dynamic content, the name of the month, can concatenate the static parts of the formula (as a string) and the dynamic variable (`date`) by simply adding them with `+`.

Sample:

```
...
var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), tz, 'MMM');
ss.renameActiveSheet(date);
// define here the cell in which you want to paste the formula:
var cell = sheet.getRange('G3');
var formula = '=iferror(VLOOKUP($A3,' + date + '!$H$14:$I$23,2,FALSE),0)';
cell.setFormula(formula);
...
```

I hope this sample helps you to understand how to set the other formulas yourself.

Comment: I have a tab called "totals" that has rows for my expense categories (e.g., Groceries) and columns for the months. Each month I have to manually copy over the vlookup to the next month's column and change the tab reference in the vlookup to the name of the new month tab (that's what my example was showing). I want the newMonthTab function to do all this when I click the button. Does that clarify?

Comment: I understand that on creation of a new month tab you want to set automaticaly a formula with dynamic content (name of the month). I will update my answer to show you how to do it.

Comment: Thanks very much. That makes sense. One additional question: how does the script know which range to update on the "totals" tab since there are 12 columns and I only want to update one, and since the "totals" tab is not the active sheet?

Comment: I see, if instead of updating a range on the newly created tab, you want to update a range on the `totals` tab - replace the line `var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();` by the line `var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('totals')` - see [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename).

Comment: Done, very helpful. Is it possible to make the getRange method dynamic so that it finds only the cells I want updated on the totals tab (because it will change every month)?

Comment: It is possible, but you have to provide some rule - e.g. paste the formula in the first free column. This you can do by retrieving the last column with [sheet.getLastColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastcolumn) and defining [`cell=sheet.getRange(row, column)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column).

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out. Appreciate your help. Could you explain why you need the " + " in ' + date + ' or point me to documentation?

Comment: It is an easy  way to concatenate strings in Javascript. You can have a look [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170404182053/https://jsperf.com/concat-vs-plus-vs-join) and [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/js/string_concat.php).